# Audiokit for backend

Tags: audiokit

I am working on a project and I am thinking to take audiokit core to the backend using vapor. 
Any of you guys have any suggestions.
If there is any other alternatives with other programming languages please let me know.

Comment: I think this would work fine and I'd be curious to see what issues you come up against. Are you basically looking to render audio output to a file and then serve that file?

Comment: Yes. I will also implement ai to master audio files.